# Apache Wamp - A weird log request. Possible exploitation?

Tags: apache, assembly, wamp, opcode, shellcode

I left my server open for a couple of hours, then I notice an IP address coming from a weird location.
It's not a page request, it looks like some operands/opcodes or perhaps shell code (if that's possible).

It looks like this:

**IP ADDR - - [27/May/2014:17:38:10 +0000] "\xbc,\xce\xb0~?:\x9e\xf7}O\xe6)f\xcc]M\"" 200 4201**

Should I be worried or what exactly does that mean? Because I see it succeeded with 200 and I don't know what to think.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of looks like encoded byte sequences for possible Unicode characters. Coming from a typical bot trying a bunch of exploits on your web-server and/or scripts.

You can find out exactly what the results (page) of that URL is by opening your Browser and going to:

`http://domain.name/\xbc,\xce\xb0~?:\x9e\xf7}O\xe6)f\xcc]M\"`